# Find a value in an object containing nested objects and array

Tags: javascript

I have the following object and a value -

```
{
   location:"xyz",
   title:"abc",
   company: {
         address:"address can have spaces",
         name:"name"
   },
   array-key :[
         { skill : "skill1"},
         { skill : "skill2"},
         { skill : "skill3"}
   ],
   description :"brief description"
}
```

and now I have a value - "spaces", now I want to check if "spaces" is present in the object at any level. If "spaces" is present function should return true.

I tried the recursive way but how should I handle the array?

Answer (score 2):

One useful trick for iterating recursively over an object is to use the `replacer` parameter to `JSON.stringify`.

```
function findString(obj, regexp) {
  let found = false;

  JSON.stringify(obj, (k, v) => {
    if (found || typeof v === 'string' && regexp.test(v)) found = true;
    else return v;
  });

  return found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness with iterating all levels recursively and checking the value either strict or as string and with [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

```js
function check(object, value) {
    return Object.keys(object).some(function (key) {
        if (object[key] && typeof object[key] === 'object') {
            return check(object[key], value);
        }
        return object[key] === value || object[key].toString().indexOf(value) + 1;
    });
}

var data = { location: "xyz", title: "abc", company: { address: "address can have spaces", name: "name" }, arrayKey: [{ skill: "skill1" }, { skill: "skill2" }, { skill: "skill3" }], description: "brief description" };

console.log(check(data, "spaces"));
console.log(check(data, "foo"));
```